# how solve this error: g++ :error: unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=cortex-a15.cortex-a7'

Tags: linux, qt, g++, qt5, odroid

I decide to Compilie Qt5.8 on XU4 by this guide :
http://freecode.hu/sbcomp/2016/08/15/compiling-qt-5-8-on-odroid-xu4/
but in step 4 , i get this error:

```
make:warning:file '/usr/include/string.h' has modification time 1e+07 s in the future
g++-4.8.real:error:unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=cortex-a15.cortex-a7'
g++-4.8.real:note:valid argumentd to '-mtune=' are: arm1020e ....
```

please help me to solve this error,
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after one hour,i solved my problem by editing qmake.config file:
changing this line which that tutorial said:
    QMAKE_CFLAGS   +=  -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtune=cortex-a15.cortex-a7  -mfloat-abi=hard

to this :
    QMAKE_CFLAGS   +=  -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtune=cortex-a15 -mtune=cortex-a7  -mfloat-abi=hard